# How to implement drag to change order of relative positioned elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I have a generic HTML like this

```
<div>
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <span>Item 4</span>
</div>
```

And I need to implement a drag-to-change-order, being able to drag each item to change the order, like you can drag an image in a text editor and drop it between words, similar to how you you can do in Mail on ios or in the Mac Dock, but with text.

Like this: http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/1921/v57sibdzorpefuaqozisso.mp4

[image]

When a user drag something and change the order, I need the actual DOM to be in that order, and not just appear on the screen like when you do with `position:absolute`.

The first idea I had is to lift the element to position absolute, computing the coordinates, and when you drop, calculate where it should be relative to other elements and then `position:relative` back.

But I'm not sure if it's a good approach, and the implementation is not quite simple.
And it's not what I would consider a elegant solution, and I'm concerned about it turning jerky.

I rather like vanilla javascript then jquery, but it can help me to implement my own.

I already implemented drag a and drop in javascript but for absolute positioned elements and it doesn't work on relative positioned elements.

I'm looking forward ideas.

http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/BWU3m/

Comment: So where's the code with absolute positioned elements that works?

Comment: @OneTrickPony http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/BWU3m/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how you want the draggable to behave, because your image suggests one thing, while your fiddle works differently (the one with `absolute` elements that you said it works). I`ll assume here you want to be able to drag them around the document like in the image.

There are some differences between relative and absolute positioned elements. Both depend on their `offsetParent` (not necessarily `parentNode`), however on `relative` elements the top/left offset is always 0 (or the distance of the element relative to itself), unless you specify a different value. On `absolute` elements the left/top offset is the distance of the element relative to the `offsetParent` upper/left edge.

So because all your `SPAN`s start at `left:0,top:0` offset (if we don't count margin etc.), you need to take into consideration the `offsetParent` size and the original offset of the elements when calculating the left/top values you need to apply, which may be negative.

When you initialize, store the `originalOffset` somewhere for later access.

`x` should be:

```
(clientX - originalOffset - width)
```

Then make sure `x` is within

```
(-originalOffset) .. (offsetParentWidth - width - originalOffset)
```

Same for `y`, but change axis.

Another thing to consider is that inline elements don't have `clientWidth/Height`.

[Here's a fiddle with the changes I mentioned above](http://jsfiddle.net/PvK2y/). If you wish to contain the drag within the DIV, simply make the DIV the `offsetParent`.

Comment: I want it to behave like the image, but I just know how to do like the fiddle which its not what I want. but I think it need to have a absolute position at least when user is dragging. but normally it shouldn't be "floating"

Comment: Edited my question, I need something like you can drag a image in a text editor between words and other elements. Or like this http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/1921/v57sibdzorpefuaqozisso.mp4